# Does golang provide an easy way to output human readable protobuf

Tags: go, protocol-buffers

Is there a good way to get a human readable string representation of protobuf objects in golang?  Something equivalent to https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.message#Message.DebugString?

I am using https://github.com/golang/protobuf.

Comment: Are you OK with unmarshalling the object or is it a requirement that you print it when it is still a profobuf message? Also are you using this package? https://github.com/golang/protobuf

Comment: Yes, I have it unmarshalled (a proto.Message object, not a string/byte[]).  I'd prefer to use a proto.Message, but it's not a requirement.  I am using that library.

Comment: Wish I could give you an answer because I'm sure it's possible but I just haven't used the package in about a year now and don't have the time to dig through it's source.

Comment: Which protobuf implementation are you using?

Comment: https://github.com/golang/protobuf - also updated the question

Comment: I am using the grpc lib, and that also automagicly creates json marshalers. Maybe that is helpful?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I believe you're looking for [proto.MarshalTextString](https://godoc.org/github.com/golang/protobuf/proto#MarshalTextString).

```
p := &example.Test{
  Label: proto.String("this"),
  Reps:  []int64{4, 3, 2, 1},
  InnerTest: &example.Test_InnerTest{
    InnerLabel: proto.String("is the end"),
  },
}

fmt.Println(proto.MarshalTextString(p))
```

You can see an example in the Go package [test](https://github.com/golang/protobuf/blob/master/proto/text_test.go#L430).

Comment: What is the import you're using for `proto`? I'm not finding the function in `google.golang.org/protobuf/proto`

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [TextMarshaler](https://godoc.org/github.com/golang/protobuf/proto#TextMarshaler). With a slightly modified example proto:

```
p := &example.Test{
    Label: proto.String("this"),
    Reps:  []int64{4, 3, 2, 1},
    InnerTest: &example.Test_InnerTest{
        InnerLabel: proto.String("is the end"),
    },
}

t := proto.TextMarshaler{}
t.Marshal(os.Stdout, p)
```

Outputs:

```
label: "this"
reps: 4
reps: 3
reps: 2
reps: 1
inner_test: <
  inner_label: "is the end"
>
```

Answer (score 4):

Example one:

```
package main
import "google.golang.org/protobuf/types/known/structpb"

func example1(x *structpb.Struct) string {
   return x.String()
}
```

Example two:

```
package main

import (
   "google.golang.org/protobuf/proto"
   "google.golang.org/protobuf/runtime/protoimpl"
)

func example2(m proto.Message) string {
   return protoimpl.X.MessageStringOf(m)
}
```

Example three:

```
package main

import (
   "google.golang.org/protobuf/encoding/protojson"
   "google.golang.org/protobuf/proto"
)

func example3(m proto.Message) string {
   return protojson.Format(m)
}
```

Test:

```
package main
import "google.golang.org/protobuf/types/known/structpb"

func main() {
   m, err := structpb.NewStruct(map[string]interface{}{
      "month": 12, "day": 31,
   })
   if err != nil {
      panic(err)
   }
   println(example1(m))
   println(example2(m))
   println(example3(m))
}
```

Result:

```
fields:{key:"day" value:{number_value:31}} fields:{key:"month" value:{number_value:12}}
fields:{key:"day" value:{number_value:31}} fields:{key:"month" value:{number_value:12}}
{
  "day": 31,
  "month": 12
}
```

- https://godocs.io/google.golang.org/protobuf/encoding/protojson
- https://godocs.io/google.golang.org/protobuf/runtime/protoimpl
- https://godocs.io/google.golang.org/protobuf/types/known/structpb

Answer (score 1):

You can use [MarshalToString](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/golang/protobuf/jsonpb#Marshaler.MarshalToString), if you need to marshal your PB into a structured message(in JSON) for future use.

A simple example:

```golang
marshaler := &jsonpb.Marshaler{}
reqString, err := marshaler.MarshalToString(req)
log.Println("@@REQ@@", reqString)
```

Or refer to [official unit test](https://github.com/golang/protobuf/blob/master/jsonpb/json_test.go) is ok.

Answer (score 0):

Since [github.com/golang/protobuf](https://github.com/golang/protobuf.) is now deprecated, I'm writing this answer for the package [google.golang.org/protobuf](https://google.golang.org/protobuf) as it might help new readers.

The [prototext](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/protobuf/encoding/prototext) package is aimed to convert messages to and from text format. The output is human readable. Using the same example from other answers:

```
p := &example.Test{
  Label: proto.String("this"),
  Reps:  []int64{4, 3, 2, 1},
  InnerTest: &example.Test_InnerTest{
    InnerLabel: proto.String("is the end"),
  },
}

fmt.Println(prototext.Format(p))
```

However, I suggest using the [protojson](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/protobuf/encoding/protojson) package since its outputs are also human readable and it has more options available. For instance, if you want to output all the fields of the message, even those that were not populated, in a human readable manner you can do

```
p := &example.Test{
  Label: proto.String("this"),
  Reps:  []int64{4, 3, 2, 1},
  InnerTest: &example.Test_InnerTest{
    InnerLabel: proto.String("is the end"),
  },
}

fmt.Println(
    protojson.MarshalOptions{
        Multiline: true, 
        EmitUnpopulated: true,
    }.Format(p)
)
```